# Why is my subdomain redirecting to www.m.example.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a subdomain for my mobile version of my site and it is a subdomain. There are two VirtualHost config file for main domain and sub domain.

m.example.com points to example.com/m

but when I try to enter my mobile site automatically added www. to my url like **www.m.example.com/m**. On .htaccess I'm removing www. and redirecting to non-www. What causes to this direction?

**BUT when I try to get http://m.example.com/index.php I get 200 OK. Problem at m.example.com**

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**(if I delete this RewriteRules noting happen. I mean if I write www.example.com it redirecting itselft to example.com So how I it redirect to non-www version of site?)**

and my subdomain's virtual host config file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin info@example.com
  ServerName  m.example.com
  ServerAlias m.example.com

  DirectoryIndex default.php index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public_html/m/
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/example/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/example/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and my main domain'a virtual host file like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin info@example.com
  ServerName  example.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex default.php index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public_html
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/example/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/example/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: do you have any other rules or .htaccess in mobile directory?

Comment: no, there is no additional rule

Comment: Clear your browser cache or try in a new browser. Those rules should not cause www to be added to m.example.com.

Comment: Where are you enabling .htaccess at? I don't see it in the vhosts config there.